# How to get Credentials from ActiveDocument?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, vsto, sharepoint-2013

I am programming an VSTO Word Addin. This addin read information (list) from sharepoint online.

How can I get Credentials from ActiveDocument class to create a ContextClient
?

I tried to use  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

```html
ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
context.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Web web = context.Web;
context.Load(web);
context.Load(web.CurrentUser);
context.ExecuteQuery();

Web rootWeb = context.Site.RootWeb;
context.Load(rootWeb, rw => rw.Url);
context.ExecuteQuery();
rootContextUrl = context.Site.RootWeb.Url;
```

How can I make it run with Sharepoint on line. It works in Sharepoint on premise.

Thanks

Comment: Your network credentials will not work with SharePoint Online. Try ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication and pass SP online user name and creds to it : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientauthenticationmode.aspx